# Sitefinity - LINQ to SQL Limitations?

Tags: c#, sql, linq, telerik, sitefinity

I am currently building a custom MVC widget for a Sitefinity (v9.2) project.

As part of this widget there is a query to the database to retrieve a collection of a dynamic module type (articles). I am trying to get article types that contain all the labels in my Labels.PublicLabels guid list.

My current query is:

```
var collection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(articleType)
    .Where(a => a.Status == Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model.ContentLifecycleStatus.Live 
     && a.Visible == true 
     && Labels.PublicLabels.All(l => a.GetValue<IList<Guid>>("Public").Contains(l)));
```

At runtime I get an exception mentioning that 'server side not implemented'. 
 Could this be a limitation of OpenAccess?

I have tried a wide range of LINQ to SQL query combinations which have been successful, I am struggling to understand the problem here.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**
I have tried a few variations on the same query such as:

```
   var collection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(articleType)
    .Where(a => a.Status == Telerik.Sitefinity.GenericContent.Model.ContentLifecycleStatus.Live 
     && a.Visible == true 
     && Labels.PublicLabels.Any(l => a.GetValue<IList<Guid>>("Public").Contains(l)));
```

No result, I still recieve the following exception message:

Execution of 'System.Linq.Enumerable:Any(IEnumerable`1,Func`2)' on the database server side currently not implemented.

Any further advice would be greatly appreciated, for now I will assume this is to do with OpenAccess limitations around LINQ to SQL.

Comment: What is the type of the "Public" field in your dynamic module?

Comment: Hi there, the public field is a classification. So it would be a TrackedList<Guid>...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this issue. Definitely down to Open Access LINQ to SQL limitations. What I did was add an additional where clause after filtering the collection down as much as I needed to. Here is the complete query:

```
    var collection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(articleType).Where(a => a.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && a.Visible == true)
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
        .Distinct()
        .Where(a => new HashSet<Guid>(a.GetValue<IList<Guid>>("Public")).IsSupersetOf(Labels.PublicLabels));
```

I will be reporting this to Sitefinity and if they manage to put a proper fix in place I will report back.

Thank you everyone for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, this way worked for me

```
var listIds = Labels.PublicLabels;
var collection = dynamicModuleManager.GetDataItems(articleType)
   .Where(a => a.Status == ContentLifecycleStatus.Live && a.Visible == true)           
   .Where(a => a.GetValue<TrackedList<Guid>>("Public").Where(al => listIds.Contains(al)).Any());
```

I didn't compile that, let me know if it will not work for you

Comment: Hi, although your query did work, I tried something similar beforehand but it does not return what I'm after. I need to get all custom article types that contain all the labels in my public labels list. The query above will return all articles that contain any label in the public list, does that make sense?